# How to use pin 36/37 as UART0 (ALT2) modifying device tree on CM3?

Tags: compute-module-3

Those pins are defined in the [datasheet](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/RPI-CM-DATASHEET-V1_0.pdf).

I investigated in the `config.txt` but cannot see any option for those. I only see it for pins 32/33 and 40/41. I then tried checking standard softwares as wiringpi and rpio but couldn't do it with.

I managed using [raspi-gpio](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-gpio) but I would be interested in a more consistent way from modifying the devicetree, from [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.9.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dts) but this has not worked yet.

Comment: I haven't tried -- I don't have a compute module, and those GPIOs are not broken out on the normal Pis -- so won't post a complete answer, but to do this via `config.txt` you'd need a device tree overlay.   However, since UART0 is the **ALT2** function of those pins (page 19 of that datasheet), you don't need to do that; you can set them dynamically/programmatically using one of the Pi GPIO oriented libraries (libbcm2835, pigpio, etc.).  Look through the docs and find the method used to set the **alt** functions for a pin.

Comment: I can do it with raspi-gpio library but I want to do it at kernel level, not at boot time.

Comment: Then the answer is a device tree overlay.  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/device-tree

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Recompile the [dts file](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.9.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dts) modifying the gpio values by values you need.
Documentation was [there](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.9.y/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/pinctrl/brcm%2Cbcm2835-gpio.txt)